# Keeping table cells highlighted on page refreshed or logout

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a 6 column table containing data. I want to focus specifically on the drop down menu which consists of three options. When an option is selected the table cells on that row change colour. This is working perfectly using jQuery, however I want the colour to remain the same when the page is refreshed or when the user logs out. can this be achieved through the use of a database? as multiple people will be using the form so cookies may not be an option. here is a break down of my current code:

jQuery: To highlight the table cells

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var color = ['none', '#DEF3CA', '#EECFA1', '#FFCCCC'];
        $('table').on('change','select', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').css('background', color[$(':selected', this).index()]); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

The select box:

```
echo ' <select name="status">
<option></option>
<option>Approved</option>
<option>Pending</option>
<option>Dissaproved</option>
</select>';
echo "</td><td>";
```

thank you

Comment: When having multiple users, cookies/local storage is usually the way to go, and not a database, unless you already have a login system that identifies users.

Comment: is there a simple way this can be achieved using my current script? thank you